# Почему Individual User Account не активна в Asp.Net Core Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-core

Доброго времени суток, Стэковерфлоучане, при создании **ASP.NET Core** проекта пошаблону **WEB API**, при выборе способа аутенфикации пользователя "Individual User Accounts" не активна ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал переустновить **VS 2017** - не помогло, все что удалось нагуглить так это то что сейчас "Individual User Accounts" не поддерживаются в шаблоне Web API, как быть тогда в такой ситуации ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это известное ограничение. Можно либо скопировать из обычного проекта, MVC версии, либо встроить в проект самостоятельно, туториалов полно. Вообще Identity для web.api избыточно, советую вам посмотреть в сторону OAuth 2.0 и JWT решений для аутентификации в сервисах и отказаться от схемы логин+пароль.

Comment: Ок, спасибо за Ваш ответ.

Comment: Ещё один вопрос возник, скажите пожалуйста, а если в мое решение добавить два проекта: первый - Web API и представляет из себя клиентскую часть, второй - MVC и представляет из себя админку и работу с БД. Можно так делать ?

Comment: Можно, такое разделение даже приветствуется. Советую посмотреть в сторону IdentityServer4.